# Regex for matching all numbers and every first letter in words

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to define a regex which matches all numbers and only the first letter of each word in a string. The word can be preceded by an empty space or by a special character.

Example strings and matches:

```
1234 Something another thing - 1234Sat
569 Camel case is Important - 569CciI
123&else - 123e
A word here and numbers 1234 - Awhan1234
Someone 0987 and string - S0987as
```

I'm currently at this point:

```
\d*\b([a-zA-Z])
```

Which doesn't quite work as needed.
An explanation of the proposed solution would also be really helpful for me.

Comment: How doesn't it work currently?

Comment: Did you meant to write: `\d|\b([a-zA-Z])`?

Comment: The above example can be seen here: https://regex101.com/r/B480xI/3 .
@JvdV When I use your example (swapped * with |) it seems to be working as needed. Can you explain how exactly this | selector is working?

Comment: The pipe symbol is an **or** operator, meaning we looking for digits *or* letters following a word boundary.

Comment: @JvdV I see that was escaping me. This solves my issue, thank you very much! Can you add your comment as an answer, so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, change to:

```
\d|\b([a-zA-Z])
```

This is using the `|` as an **or** operator looking for digits or letters just after a word boundary.

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JnWV5J/4).

Comment: Thank you again, this solved the issue. I really appreciate the explanation as well!

Comment: @ZGanchev, you could also remove opening and closing paranthesis as that would create a capture group which I'm not sure you need in the first place?

Comment: Thanks, I tried both ways and it seems to be working (with or without parentheses). I'll remove them from the implementation, because I'm not sure how they are functioning to be honest, they were left from my previous tries.

Answer (score 1):

... [`(/\b(?:\d+|\w)/g)`](https://regex101.com/r/SDmhM0/1/) ...

```js
const sampleText = `1234 Something another thing
569 Camel case is Important
123&else
A word here and numbers 1234
Someone 0987 and string`;

// see: [https://regex101.com/r/SDmhM0/1/]
const regXMatch = (/\b(?:\d+|\w)/g);

console.log(
  sampleText
    .split('\n')
    .map(text => text.match(regXMatch).join(''))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

***Edit***

> *Thanks, but can you add an explanation how this is working? – ZGanchev*

The top most regex matches either a sequence of digit characters `\d+` or `|` a single word character `\w`. Both options are grouped `( ... )` in a non capturing (thus they will not be remembered) way `(?: ... )`. Either option has to follow a word boundary `\b`. Thus, assembling everything does look like the linked regex from above ... `/\b(?:\d+|\w)/g`.

The above example code uses a multiline string (via template syntax). In order to process each line separately one does split the string at every line break `.split('\n')`.

The resulting array then gets processes by [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a mapping lambda ...

`text => text.match(regXMatch).join('')`

... The mapper's first argument is the currently processed array item, here the single line `text` string value from the formerly created array of single lines.

`text.match(regXMatch)` returns an array of all regex matches which are immediately joined ... `text.match(regXMatch).join('')` ... into the result the OP was looking for e.g. ...

```js
// see: [https://regex101.com/r/SDmhM0/1/]
const regXMatch = (/\b(?:\d+|\w)/g);

console.log(
  "1234 Something another thing"
);
console.log(
  "1234 Something another thing".match(regXMatch)
);
console.log(
  "1234 Something another thing".match(regXMatch).join('')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Within a full iteration the array of single lines gets mapped into an array of line-acronyms.

Comment: Thanks, but can you add an explanation how this is working?